# What does exec ${PERL-perl} -Sx $0 ${1+"$@"} mean in Shell script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, perl, scripting

I'm given a task to convert a shell script which contains Shell script, Perl code to Python.

I managed to convert the Perl code to Python.

But there is this shell script statement which I didn't understand.

```
#! /usr/bin/sh
exec ${PERL-perl} -Sx $0 ${1+"$@"}
#! /opt/tools/perl5/bin/perl
Some Perl code which I converted to Python
```

What does this 2nd line means?

I understood that `$0` will be evaluated to the script name.

And I'm assuming that `${PERL-perl}` will evaluate to whatever Perl interpreter is installed on the machine (correct me if I'm wrong and also please let me know how do I mention the similar thing for Python).

Can someone explain what those remaining parameters in that `exec` command do?

Comment: What does the script do when you execute it? How would verify that you correctly converted the code if you you're not running the scripts to compare the results?

Comment: See [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun).

Comment: How to run Python interpreter instead of Perl in the shell script.
Is there anything like `${PYTHON-python}` that I can mention after `exec` command?

Comment: After reading a bit about the `-S` and `-x` options for `perl`, are you sure it makes any sense to keep these lines around if you convert the script to Python? It's really all about starting a Perl script, which you got rid of. Can't you replace the first three lines with `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or something like it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${PERL-perl}` is a [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02): if the `PERL` shell variable is unset, use `perl`, else use the content of `PERL`. (Arguably, this should be `${PERL:-perl}`, because if `PERL` is set but empty, the empty string will be used.)

`${1+"$@"}` stands for "if `$1` is set, use `"$@"` (all positional parameters), else substitute null". This is a hack for older shells that get confused by `"$@"` if there are no positional parameters and expand to a single parameter instead of none at all. Bash would work with just `"$@"` instead.

For the options to `perl`, see [`perldoc perlrun`](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun).

Comment: ok. thanks for that. and what does that `-Sx` means? The documentation says `-S` checks if the file is socket and `-x` checks if the file is executable. How can a file be both?

Comment: @Baelish2285 Perl command line options are documented [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). You're looking at something else.

Comment: I still don't understand whether the 2nd line parameters are interpreted as shell script options or perl options? Which documentation do I need to consider?

Comment: @Baelish2285 The whole line is a shell command, but `perl` takes command line options specific to Perl.

Comment: @Baelish2285, ...it's like if you run `ls -l`; the relevant meaning of `-l` is documented in the manual for `ls`, not for the shell itself. Similarly, for `perl -Sx`, it's `perl`'s manual that tells you what `-S` or `-x` mean in that context.